# Validate image-size in CakePHP model

Tags: cakephp

How do I validate an image's file size in a model in CakePHP?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't reinvent the wheel here when there are [plugins available](https://github.com/davidpersson/media) that do both [image size validation](https://github.com/davidpersson/media/blob/455db38a0b4ee3aaffae304e1b52bb62f99b2982/docs/TUTORIAL#L221) and [image resizing](https://github.com/davidpersson/media/blob/455db38a0b4ee3aaffae304e1b52bb62f99b2982/docs/TUTORIAL#L120).

Comment: This does nothing to answer the question - it's worth putting as a comment, but it's not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [upload pack plugin](https://github.com/szajbus/uploadpack) to upload images. It allows [validation of uploaded files](https://github.com/szajbus/uploadpack#you-can-validate-uploaded-files), including the size. Other than that you can add [your own validation rules](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#adding-your-own-validation-methods). What it would look like is case specific. Generally you would return [filesize('/tmp/your-uploaded-file')](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php) < $limit